# How to lambdify a list of strings with SymPy in Julia?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, julia, sympy, lambdify

Using SymPy in Julia, how can I transform the example input

`feature_names = ["1", "x", "y", "z", "x^2", "x y", "x z", "y^2", "y z", "z^2"]`

into a callable method `f(x, y, z)` which returns the evaluation of the expressions like

```
julia >>> f(1, 2, 3)
julia >>> 10-element Vector{float64}:
          [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't quite what you are asking, as expressions like "x y" don't work with `sympify`, so I had to add `*` as needed, but using `sympify` and `free_symbols` allows this to be automated:

```
feature_names = ["1", "x", "y", "z", "x^2", "x*y", "x*z", "y^2", "y*z", "z^2"]

using SymPy
function F(feature_names)

    xs = sympy.sympify.(feature_names)
    vars = free_symbols(xs)
    function(as...)
        subs.(xs, (vars .=> as)...)
    end
end

λ = F(feature_names)
λ(1,2,3)
```

The ordering of the variables in the lamda is determined calling `sortperm` on the stringified symbols, as that is how `free_symbols` orders things.

Answer (score 2):

In Julia you could do something like this:

```
using SymPy
@vars x y z

feature_names = [1, x, y, z, x^2, x*y, x*z, y^2, y*z, z^2]

f(a,b,c) = feature_names.evalf(subs=Dict(x=>a,y=>b,z=>c)) |> N |> vec

f(1,2,3) # [1.0,1.0,2.0,...]
```

or, more in general,:

```
solveMultipleSympyFunctions(values,sympy_symbols,expressions) = expressions.evalf(subs=Dict(zip(sympy_symbols,values))) |> N |> vec

solveMultipleSympyFunctions([1,2,3],[x,y,z],feature_names)
```

The `N(.)` function is to retrieve a numerical output instead of a number that is still a symbol, and `vec()` is to transform the output, that is in matrix form, to a vector as in your request. Finally, `|>` is the pipe operator (just for convenience instead of writing `vec(N(...))`)

**EDIT:**

I did try several ways to start the expressions from a vector of strings, but none of the above works:

```
feature_names_string = ["1", "x", "y", "z", "x^2", "x*y", "x*z", "y^2", "y*z", "z^2"]
feature_names = symbols.(feature_names_string)
feature_names = symbols.(Symbol.(feature_names_string))
feature_names = sympy.Function.(feature_names_string)
feature_names = convert.(Sym,sympy.Function.(feature_names_string))
feature_names = Sym(feature_names_string)
feature_names = Sym.(feature_names_string)
feature_names = Sym.(sympy.Function.(feature_names_string))
feature_names = sympy.Function.(Sym.(feature_names_string))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Great suggestion. One question: Is there a way to get from the list of strings `feature_names` to the list of expressions in your code procedurally?

Comment: @Felix: I edited the answer, but no.. unfortunatly I has been unable to find a way. You can write in the [SymPy.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/SymPy.jl) issue tracker or in https://discourse.julialang.org to try to get more qualified answers...

Comment: Thanks for editing. Thanks also for the hint of filing an issue. One last question: Is it possible to get each individual entry of `feature_names` "translated" into expressions? I was thinking of something like `feature = "x y"` into `f(x,y,z)`. Then one courd iterate through the list.