# LoadError: MethodError: "Method too new to be called from this world context." in Julia

Tags: julia, sympy

Can someone explain in simple terms why this error occurs and how it can be avoided except not placing the code in `main` in a function?

Please refer to question [Improving the performance of SymPy function generated from string in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467593/improving-the-performance-of-sympy-function-generated-from-string-in-julia) for the function `string_to_func`.

Works:

```
using SymPy

function string_to_func(function_string)
    func_lambdify = lambdify(SymPy.sympify(function_string), invoke_latest=false)
    @eval func(x, y, z) = ($func_lambdify)(x, y, z)
    return Nothing
end

function_string = "x + y + z"
string_to_func(function_string)
result = func(1, 2, 3)
```

Throws Error:

```
using SymPy

function string_to_func(function_string)
    expr = lambdify(SymPy.sympify(function_string), invoke_latest=false)
    @eval func(x, y, z) = ($expr)(x, y, z)
    return Nothing
end

function main()
    function_string = "x + y + z"
    string_to_func(function_string)
    result = func(1, 2, 3)
end

main()
```

Anonymized Error Message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching func(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 29676, while current world is 29678.
Closest candidates are:
  func(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at path_to_folder\test.jl:5 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
Stacktrace:
 [1] main()
   @ Main path_to_folder\test.jl:12
 [2] top-level scope
   @ path_to_folder\test.jl:15
in expression starting at path_to_folder\test.jl:15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke `func` using `Base.invokelatest`, i.e.

```
function main()
    function_string = "x + y + z"
    string_to_func(function_string)
    result = Base.invokelatest(func, 1, 2, 3)
end
```

See [the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Redefining-Methods) for further details about world age and why `invokelatest` is needed here.

I should also mention [GeneratedFunctions.jl](https://github.com/SciML/RuntimeGeneratedFunctions.jl) that can avoid some of the overhead associated with `invokelatest`, although it has it is own caveats since its somewhat of a hack.